# Vectorized solution for using previous value in a column under some condition

Tags: r, tidyverse

This is probably easy, but beyond a clunky for loop I haven't been able to find a vectorized solution for this.

```
df <- tibble(a=c(1,2,3,4,3,2,5,6,9), b=c(1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,9))
```

Column `a` should be continuously increasing and should look like column `b`. So, whenever the next value in `a` is smaller than the previous value in `a`, the previous value should be used instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cummax()` from base `R`:

```
df[["b1"]] <- cummax(df[["a"]])

> df
  a b b1
1 1 1  1
2 2 2  2
3 3 3  3
4 4 4  4
5 3 4  4
6 2 4  4
7 5 5  5
8 6 6  6
9 9 9  9
```

Using more `dplyr` syntax:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(b1 = cummax(a))
```

Comment: That looks elegant. Will give it a try!

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution with a base function that does exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lag` and `fill` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 mutate(b1 = replace(a, a < lag(a), NA)) %>%
 fill(b1)


#      a     b    b1
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     2     2     2
#3     3     3     3
#4     4     4     4
#5     3     4     4
#6     2     4     4
#7     5     5     5
#8     6     6     6
#9     9     9     9
```

The logic being we replace the values in `a` with `NA` where the previous value is greater than the next and then use `fill` to replace those `NA`s with last non-NA value.

Comment: Oh, nice. I had a "solution" with `lag`, but that would fail if there two smaller values in a row. I'll give it a try!